swiper version 11 error while importing import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing '../shared.js' instead. 1 import type { SwiperModule } from '../shared.d.ts';
when i try to import navigation for swiper
my angular version: "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.0",
"@angular/core": "^14.2.0",
swiper version:    "swiper": "^11.1.9",
basically  

is not working so itried to import naviagtion using
import { Navigation, Pagination } from 'swiper/modules';
error:An import path cannot end with a '.d.ts' extension. Consider importing '../shared.js' instead. 1 import type { SwiperModule } from '../shared.d.ts';
